# Can require but not import if it is a globally installed module

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have Node 14.11.0. My PC has the [qrcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode) module installed globally. The `NODE_PATH` environment value is pointing to the correct folder.

In one Node Javascript project, `const qrcode = require("qrcode");` runs without problem, which can confirm that the module is present and reachable.

In another project on the same PC, I have these lines in `...\dist\index.js`:

```
import fs from "fs";
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";
import qrcode from "qrcode";
```

`nodemailer` is a locally installed npm module, and lines 1 and 2 run fine, which can confirm I have the appropriate Node version.

The third line will give:

```
null: Uncaught Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'qrcode' imported from d:\Documents\proj\dist\index.js
Did you mean to import qrcode/lib/index.js?
```

If it is relevant information, the error is thrown even before the first line is stepped through.

Why is this error happening? Is it a known issue that `import` will not work with a globally installed Node module?

Answer (score 0):

IMPORT IS PART OF JS NOT NODE. GLOBAL MODULES ARE A PART OF NODEJS. SO, YOU MUST LOCALLY INSTALL THE MODULES